# laravel migration changes not reflecting

Tags: php, laravel

i changed my post_id foreign key to posts_id in images migration in order for the relationship to work. however after changing, the insertion of images in images table is still picking post_id which is giving me an error column  not found. i tried cache:clear and config but nothing worked. post_id is nowhere in my code

### postcontroller

```
 public function store( Request $request )
{    
    $data = request()->validate([
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'about' => 'required',
        'category' => '',
        'expire_date' => '',
        

    ]); 
if (Auth::guard('web')->check())
     {
       $user = Auth::user();
       $post = new Post();

       /*$post = $user->posts()->create([
            'about' => $data['about'],
            'category' => $data['category'],
            'expire_date' => $data['expire_date'],
            
        ]);*/
        if($request->hasFile('image'))
        {
          $files = $request->file('image');
          
          
          
          foreach($files as $file)
          {
            
            $name = time().'-'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $name = str_replace('','-',$name);
            echo $name;
            
            $file->move('images',$name);
            
            $post->images()->create(['image' => $name ]);
           

          }
        }
       


        $user = Auth::guard('web')->id() ;

        return redirect()->route('home',['user'=>$user]);

        
    }


  }
```

### postmodel

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

### images model

```
class images extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
    'posts_id',
    'image'
];
 
public function posts(){
    return $this->belongTo(Posts::class);

}
}
```

### posts migration

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->uuid('user_id')->nullable;
        $table->uuid('admin_id')->nullable;
        $table->string('category')->nullable;
        $table->string('about');
       
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

### images migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('posts_id');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->timestamps();
        
        $table->index('posts_id');

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Images model

```php
public function posts(){
    return $this->belongTo(Posts::class);
}
```

to

```php
public function posts(){
    return $this->belongTo(Posts::class, 'posts_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you change it? Laravel can handle this for you if leave it to post_id. Otherwise you’ll have to update the relation posts in your images model by adding extra arguments. See the documentation: laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->belongTo(Posts::class, 'posts_id');
}
```

Comment: i changed it because it was saying post_id cannot be null when i tried to insert the  images

Comment: thanks i realized why post_id wasn't working is because i forgot to remove the comment on the post create. The foreign key was correct little did i know.